# Perform raster calculation in python using rasterio

Tags: python, rasterio

I am trying to multiply two rasters (raster1 & raster2) together and then write a raster using the result of the multiplication.

I can read the input rasters using the rasterio package in python but I am struggling to write the output raster to a file.

Where am I going wrong?

```
rasterio version 1.3.8
Python 3.10.8

The meta data for the input rasters are:

raster1:
Name    JRC_forest_yield_upsampled_to_1km
Path    C:\Users\Input_datasets\Forest_Biomass_Map\JRC_forest_yield_upsampled_to_1km.tif
Extent  900000.0000000000000000,900000.0000000000000000 : 7400000.0000000000000000,5416000.0000000000000000
Width   6500
Height  4516
Data type   Float64 - Sixty four bit floating point
GDAL Driver Description GTiff
GDAL Driver Metadata    GeoTIFF
Compression LZW
CRS EPSG:3035 - ETRS89-extended / LAEA Europe

raster2:
Name    eu_nuts0_for_rents_prices_rast
Path    C:\Users\Throughput_datasets\eu_nuts0_for_rents_prices_rast.tif
Extent  900000.0000000000000000,900000.0000000000000000 : 7400000.0000000000000000,5416000.0000000000000000
Width   6500
Height  4516
Data type   Float32 - Thirty two bit floating point
GDAL Driver Description GTiff
GDAL Driver Metadata    GeoTIFF
Compression (blank in QGIS)
CRS EPSG:3035 - ETRS89-extended / LAEA Europe
```

Error:

```
(.venv) C:\Users\spencerd\Documents> raster_calculator.py    
c:\Users\spencerd\Documents\.venv\lib\site-packages\rasterio\__init__.py:329: NotGeoreferencedWarning: Dataset has no geotransform, gcps, or rpcs. The identity matrix will be returned.
  dataset = writer(
```

Script:

```
import rasterio
from rasterio import features
from rasterio.enums import MergeAlg
from rasterio.plot import show
from numpy import int16

# Paths to the input raster files
raster1_path = 'C:/Users/Spatial datasets/EULandClass/EU_landSystem.tif'
raster_woody_path = 'C:/Users/Spatial datasets/European countries/Input_datasets/Forest_Biomass_Map/JRC_forest_yield_upsampled_to_1km.tif'
raster2_path = 'C:/Users/Throughput_datasets/eu_nuts0_for_rents_prices_rast.tif'

# Open the input raster files and plot

rast1 = rasterio.open(raster_woody_path).read()
rast2 = rasterio.open(raster2_path).read()

result = rast1 * rast2
result

# define output file path and parameters
output_path = "C:/Users/Throughput_datasets/eu_forestry_monetary_yields_unmasked.tif"


# Write the result to a new raster file
with rasterio.open(output_path, 
                   'w',
                   width=6500,
                   height=4516,
                   count=1,
                   crs='epsg:3050',
                   dtype='float32',
                   nodata=-0,
                   driver='GTiff',
                   transform= None) as dst:
    dst.write(result)
```

From this code I wanted to save the resulting raster "result" to the filepath "output_path" but I just get an error, what do I need to do differently?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to take the required parameters from one of the rasters you use as source ones (it includes width, height, crs etc).

Edit the last piece of your code this way:

```
# Write the result to a new raster file
kwargs = rast1.meta
kwargs.update(
    dtype=rasterio.float32,
    count=1)

with rasterio.open(output_path, 'w', **kwargs) as dst:
    dst.write_band(1, result.astype(rasterio.float32))
```